# How to stop exporting rust_eh_personality?

Tags: rust

Given this simple code:

code:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn testing() -> bool {
  false
}
```

cargo.toml:

```
...

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
...
```

and I end up with:

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for main.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000014F0 rust_eh_personality = rust_eh_personality
          2    1 00001000 testing = testing
```

How can I stop rust from exporting rust_eh_personality?

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/92102